# How to apply css class to a <tr> based on respective $value in a <td> of that row in a repeat region

Tags: php, css

I have the following code:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><?php>echo $recordset['columnname1']; ?></td>
   <td><?php>echo $recordset['columnname2']; ?></td>
   <td><?php>echo $recordset['columnname3']; ?></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

How can I add a class to the entire row based on the text value of `$recordset['columnname1']` using `PHP`?

Comment: Do you mean having different class for different `td`?

Comment: what is `$recordset['columnname1']`? I mean what is the value of it?

Comment: you should define an id for the particular <td>.. then you can add a class by using jquery

Comment: @asprin, just one class based on value ofnthe first td.

Comment: @Pankit Kapadia, yes it is.

Comment: @Edwin Alex, can you give me an example of your sugestion, assigning an ID and using jquery? Seems like good idea too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table>
   <tr class="<?php echo $recordset['columnname1'] ?>">
       ......
   </tr>
</table>
```

Then it'll add class to the entire row of those td.

Comment: And see @Pankit Kapadia for your typo

Answer (score 4):

Its a typo..

It would be like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $recordset['columnname1']; ?></td>
                ^------------- Removed > from here. It was incorrect syntax.
       <td><?php echo $recordset['columnname2']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $recordset['columnname3']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And if the value of `$recordset['columnname1']` is your class name and you want to apply it on a row then you will need to give `class` to `<tr>`

```
<table>
    <tr class="<?php echo $recordset['columnname1']; ?>">
        <td>..</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="<?php echo $recordset['columnname2']; ?>">
        <td>..</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, actually, there is not syntax error in OP's code. It will output `echo $recordset['columnname1']; echo  $recordset['columnname1'];  echo $recordset['columnname3'];`. Not logical, of course. ;)

Comment: @PLB - Edited. :) i think its a typo because he actually writing `<td>`. :)

Comment: @PankitKapadia Yes, and probably, because of `First of all you have _syntax error_ writing php code.` Anyway I think you should not be downvoted since your answer contains solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simple put an `if` condition

```
<table>
  <tr <?php if($recordset["columnname1"] == "myvalue") echo 'class="myclass"'; ?> >
   <td><?php echo $recordset['columnname1']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $recordset['columnname2']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $recordset['columnname3']; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```